# Aborting Simultaneous Readied Actions

Tags: dnd-5e, readied-action

Expanding on [How are simultaneously-triggered Readied actions resolved?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68925/how-are-simultaneously-triggered-readied-actions-resolved)

Last session, I was DM and the party was engaging an Earth Elemental which was using its *Earth Glide* to hide in the rocks, pop out and attack and glide away. The party countered, as expected, by taking the Ready action. Specifically, the cleric (higher in initiative) readied *Banishment* and then the Bard readied *Hold Monster* with the trigger "when the damn thing pops out of the wall"; both excellent choices.

So, the elemental appears, the trigger is activated, the Cleric acts and succeeds so the Bard is left with no valid target.

**My question is, what if the roles were reversed. If the Bard succeeded in holding the elemental, could the Cleric have aborted the Banishment?**

Clearly, the Cleric could (should?) have used a different trigger: "if the Bard's spell fails", however, for this question, assume they were both acting on the same trigger.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can always ignore the trigger for a Readied action. From the PHB section on the Ready action, page 193:

> When
>   the
>   trigger
>   occurs,
>   you
>   can
>   either
>   take
>   your
>   reaction
>   right
>   after
>   the
>   trigger
>   finishes
>   or
>   ignore
>   the
>   trigger.

As SevenSidedDie points out, [the spell slot is spent regardless of whether the Cleric chooses to react to the trigger](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59332/does-a-readied-spell-immediately-use-a-spell-slot).