# Can my familiar cast Mending on a mummy?

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars, cantrips

I am a Warlock with an [Imp](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/imp-familiar-variant) familiar. Can I send my familiar to cast [Mending](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mending) on a mummy with the intent to have all or some of the torn wrappings be mended and therefore restrain, blind, or just distract it?

Comment: I'm also concerned that you might be trying to elicit opinions about how effective mending might be against a Mummy. We can tell you the by-the-book answer, but we generally won't comment on adding special effects that the rules don't allow. There is an exception for asking about balance concerns related to allowing the special effects, though.

Comment: If you really are looking for some back-and-forth about what the mending spell *might* do, there are plenty of [forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) that are frequented by RPG players.

Comment: Related: [What are the limits of the spell Mending?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/49291), [Can the Mending cantrip affix any surface to any other surface?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/158082), [Can objects be folded or otherwise compressed to satisfy Mending's requirements?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/119079)

Comment: Is there something specific in the description of the Mending spell that makes you believe this idea would work by RAW?

Comment: Possibly relevant to the other half of the question, about (presumably) having the familiar deliver the spell: [Can a familiar from the Find Familiar spell deliver a touch spell with a long casting time?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/143521/can-a-familiar-from-the-find-familiar-spell-deliver-a-touch-spell-with-a-long-ca) (although currently the answers seem inconclusive)

Answer (score 15):

## Short answer, no

One, familiars generally don't cast spells. The owner casts the spell and it can be delivered by a familiar. That will be in a different point. Imps, can polymorph and turn invisible, but they don't have the Mending cantrip (unless homebrewed for some reason). Therefore I have to assume you mean that the magic user casts Mending, and it will delivered via familiar.

Two, Mending takes 1 minute to cast. If it was an action, then you might have a chance. But this will take 10 rounds to complete. That's 10 rounds while in combat with the Mummy (you can't cast it as a Readied spell). Which means depending on how your DM rules it, 10 rounds where you can take no other action and at the end, spend the 11th round delivering the spell, -or- 10 rounds with your Imp in constant contact with the Mummy with the spell going off at the end.

And while combat with a Mummy can take a while, there are much better ways to use your time.

Three, nowhere in the rules does it suggest that Mending would somehow bind up a Mummy. Per the rules of Mending, it "repairs a single break or tear" so only one loop of cloth would be stitched back together.

Unless you could somehow specify exactly which tear would be the one that trips the Mummy up, it would be kind of pointless.

Comment: Point three - exactly - I would argue that mending if anything would repair wrappings of the mummy that came loose over the loooong time it existed^^ so in fact making the mummy "newer", "stronger" -which certainly isnt the desired effect

Comment: Also relevant is the idea that mummies will have been wrapped in such a way that they are apparently still capable of locomotion, so even if we repair the wrappings, they would presumably just tighten up and hug the mummy's body, not necessarily trip it. You would have to wrap the mummy in an abnormal way in order for it to trip over its own wrappings. Or unwrap it.